# Creating a collision effect three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

So for a game that I am making (my first game) I have made an endless scroller and everything is working perfect. The only issue I am have is with creating a collision like effect. For the time being the only thing I want to happen when the objects collide is to post to the console saying 'collision'. This is the collision function that I have made :

```
function collision () {
  distance = Math.sqrt(
              ((engine.x - obstacles[i].x) * (engine.x – obstacles[i].x))
            + ((engine.y - obstacles[i].y) * (engine.y – obstacles[i].y))
             );
       if (distance < engine.radius + obstacles[i].radius)
       {
         console.log("collision");
           //objects should collide
       }
}
```

Engine in this case being a cube and the `obstacles[i]` array is an series of cylinders coming toward the cube.

and I have called the function within my ini function(). But for some reason I am not getting anything posted to the console.

I may be way off here, but if anyone has any suggestions that would be great.

Comment: hi are you using intersect and raycaster?

Comment: @headmax no I am not

Comment: I guess it is the right way, you got a component of all object, camera, projection from the scene and also take `intersect` "collide" gave you the right position return `vector3` or `vector4` depends of what you are using and this `without any math` they do it for you ;).

Comment: @headmax kinda wanna do it without using that if possible?

Comment: yes you could if your project is small  but can take mutch processor time if it's for a big dev, and you lost something that already integrated inside the api for you.